# Storing and processing millions of images in a project

Tags: image, image-processing, neural-network, distributed-computing, bigdata

I have a project that will generate a huge number of images. (1 000 000 sorry i erred)
I need to process every image through algorithm.
Can you advice me an archinecture for this project?

It is proprietary algorithm in the area of computer vision.

Average size of image is near 20 kB
I need to process them when they are uploaded and 1 or 2 times on request.
On average, once a day I get a million images, each of which I will need to navigate through the algorithm 1-2 times per day.

Yep most often, the image will be stored on a local disk

When i process images i will generate new image.

### Current view:

Most likely i will have a few servers (i do not own) for each of the servers i have to perform the procedure described above.
Internet bandwidth between servers is very thin (about 1 Mb \ s) but for me it is necessary to exchange messages between servers (update coefficients of the neural network) and update algorithm.

On current hardware (intel family 6 model 26) it is about 10 minutes to complete full procedure for 50 000 images.

### May be

Where will be wide internel channels so i can upload this images to servers i have.

Comment: What kind of processing? Is it something common, like resizing or watermarking, or some proprietary algorithm?

Comment: It is proprietary algorithm in the area of computer vision.

Comment: How large are the images? How often will you be processing them? Can they be stored locally on some disk drive? When you process them will you be changing them? Can you add some details to your question.

Comment: I just updated question

Comment: What kind of hardware do you have available? How long does your algorithm take to process one image? What kind of throughput do you need to meet? Do you have any ideas to solve your problem that will help us understand what you are looking for better?

Comment: Du you mean you have one million or one billion images? There seems to be a contradiction. ("(1 000 000 sorry i erred)" compared to "once a day I get a billion images"). Please edit.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know much about images. But i guess this should help http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/why-cloudera/hadoop-and-big-data.html

Also please let us know what kind of processing you are talking about and when you are saying huge number of images. How much do you expect per hour or per day ?